# Find node with element in array

Tags: graph, neo4j, cypher, nosql

I can't find anywhere on the Internet a cypher query that allow me to find all the nodes that contain a specific element in an array.

To give you an example, I have

```
0 {name:"John", email:["j@example.com", "j@test.com"]}
```

What query would find John by email?

Answer (score 1):

I just realised that it was easier than expected, but someone might have a better answer.

```
MATCH (n)
WHERE "j@example.com" IN n.emails
RETURN collect(n)
```